# python script does not start at boot

Tags: python, boot

I follow [this blog](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-run-a-python-program-at-startup-on-your-raspberry-pi-d5cc1730d4db) to the t to start a python script on startup.
(Rasperi pi4B OS 64bit)

**my launcher.sh works fine she trying sh launcher.sh**

the file looks like:

```
cd /home/pi/Documents
PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
python3 /home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_ACC.py
```

however using it with crontab -e

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/Documents/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

it just does not work (tried in different configurations)
I get always the error

> File "/home/pi/Documents/RaspberryPi_ACC.py", line 12, in 
> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

pandas is installed, and as I mentioned above, trying with sh launcher.sh does launch without a problem.

I am clueless. Thanks

Comment: I believe apps run with crontab will run as root user. Did you install pandas with sudo?

Comment: ahh no. I just used pip install pandas.

Comment: Can't see any Pi relevance to this question.

Comment: yes, I now noticed that it might be more of an Ubuntu crontab problem. But I guess/hope a lot of users are also knowledgable in Ubuntu?

Comment: Try ‘sudo pip3 install pandas’

Comment: Hey that seems to be it. Now it doesn't find another module... which means pandas is found. Thanks so much. On to sudo installing a lot of models :-)

Comment: If it does not need to run under root, you can also put it in your own `crontab`.

Comment: Could you add an example how to do this? Than I can also vote on it. Cheers